# How to parse query string of a Uri by keeping the encoding?

Tags: c#, url, query-string, urlencode

I'm tryig to parse a query string's parameters into a `NameValueCollection`, using `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` method:

```
var queryParams = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
```

The problem is, when I have an encoded parameter value, such as "`%3Cscript%3Ealert(%27abc%27)%3C%2Fscript%3E`" and I try to get it via a key, I get the decoded version.

```
var queryString = "?name=%3Cscript%3Ealert(%27abc%27)%3C%2Fscript%3E";
var queryParams = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString); 
var nameValue = queryParams["name"] //<script>alert('abc')</script>
```

When I look at the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel.Internals/System/Runtime/UrlUtility.cs,3351648efbac7022,references) I can see that this is because of a `boolean` parameter `urlencoded` which I have no way to change. So, I'm guessing this is the expected behaviour, although I'm not sure why there is no option to change this value.

Is there any other method that will allow me to parse a query string without messing with the encoding, or am I missing something here?

Comment: What if just HttpUtility.UrlEncode nameValue back?

Comment: @Evk that wouldn't work if I have a decoded value. I wanna keep encoding as it is. if it's decoded it should remain that way.

Comment: Then without some reflection I'm not sure you can do that (with HttpUtility). You don't want to use reflection I suppose?

Comment: @Evk nope, I would manually parse or copy this class and modify it instead.

Comment: With reflection you can just instantiate HttpValueCollection manually. Without it you can just copy whole HttpValueCollection class from reference source (it's small) and replace UrlUtility with HttpUtility if necessary.

Comment: There's always the quick and dangerous way: var queryParams = queryString.Substring(1).Split('&').Select(s => s.Split('=')).ToDictionary(kv => kv[0], kv => kv[1]) :)